# How to set XAML in Default of Access 2010 column?

Tags: wpf, ms-access, richtextbox, ms-access-2010

I need save RichTextBox content in the Access 2010 database, column Description, type memo and not Null, so I converted it to XAML code for save, but some time this RichTextBox can has no content for save, so when my column Description is empty, it will make error of execution when I try load.

I had take RichTextBox content when it's empty, and it returned follow code

```
    <FlowDocument AllowDrop="True" NumberSubstitution.CultureSource="User" 
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"><Paragraph /></FlowDocument>
```

So I think, maybe I can put it code in the Description Default value, but I don't know how to do it, because it is not a simple text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> maybe I can put it code in the Description Default value, but I don't know how to do it, because it is not a simple text

HTML, XML and similar variants tend not to pay attention to line breaks between elements, so perhaps you can specify the default field value in your question as one long string. Alternatively, your form code could test the RichTextBox for an empty description and then insert the default code into the database directly instead of trying to insert the "value" of the empty RichTextBox (which causes the runtime error).